# Numpy How to find how many times elements of a column are contained in an array without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let A and B be:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[5, 5, 5], [7, 8, 6]])
B = np.array([[5, 5], [6, 6], [9, 8]])
```

How can I, without loops, find how many times each column contents in A, (in any order) is contained in every column of B such that the result would be C:

```py
C = np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

Explanation of C: first element is 0 because (5, 7) (elements of first column of A) do not exist in any column of B, second element of C is 1 because (5, 8) is contained in second column of B (notice that the 6 in the middle doesnt affect the result), and third element of C is 2 because (5, 6) is contained in every column of B, so a total of 2 times.

Comment: `np.equal.outer(A,B).any(-2).all(0).sum(1)`, a loop should be faster than an outer (A.shape x B.shape) intermediate array for larger arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to work perfectly. If you don't mind would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The solution is suboptimal with a complexity of O(n^4). I recommend checking the premise of the question and expanding the answers to an efficient solution including loops.